# How to determine application file path on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, 64-bit

I'm trying to determine my application's directory path on Windows 7 x64 using `qApp->applicationDirPath()`.
On Windows 7 x32 and other platforms (XP 32, 64) it works fine. But when application's running from "`C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication`" something happens. It returns "`C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication\`" instead of "`C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication\`". What's wrong with it?

I've tried to change UAC settings, but it was unsuccessfully. No effect. Or, perhaps, I was wrong?

Any idea? How can I determine real directory on Windows 7 x64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned path is in fact the real path on the harddisk. Whenever you install something to C:\ under Windows 7-64, this is in fact sent to a different folder and only presented virtually under C:.
You can test this with a Dos Box.

Comment: But on the different machines I've different effect. On my (where I'm making application) path `C:\Program Files (x86)`. On user's machine path is `C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x64)`. Both have Windows 7 x64. What's wrong?

Comment: I've tried to use `argv[0]` and now it works. The same path on different computers.

Answer (score 1):

When you install your application, your installation process needs to be running with administrative rights or needs to request elavated privileges otherwise it won't have write access to the Program Files directories.

If you don't have the adequate privileges, your attempts to write anything to the Program Files directory will automatically be virtualized.

Quoting from the [Microsoft Knowledge base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387):

> When this application writes to a system location, such as to the %programfiles% folder, Windows Vista and Windows 7 redirect write operations and read operations to a user-specific location in the user’s profile folder (%localappdata%\VirtualStore). By default, this location is C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Application_name.

Assumedly on one of the computers the person doing the installation had adequate rights, or had UAC disabled. That's why it worked on one but not the other.

Comment: Why it doesn't work when UAC's disabled? OK, I'll try to run my application with admin's rights (I'll force it).